# JSON or any up-to-date weather stream

Tags: json, weather

I have a new website that will need to display a water display in a div

I'd like to display :

- place name
- weater in c or f
- icon
- text of what the icon mean

I need to get weather from CANADA (QUEBEC)
it must look like : havre-saint-pierre : aujourdhui : 18c, passages nuageux

Where and how can I get a up-to-date stream of weather data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget yahoo, the most easy and fast way to do that is with google weather API, you didnt specify what programing skill you have, so i will asume you know php and html, here is your code:

```
<?
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=jakarta');
$information = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_information");
$current = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/current_conditions");
$forecast_list = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_conditions");
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Weather API</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?= print $information[0]->city['data']; ?></h1>
        <h2>Today's weather</h2>
        <div class="weather">       
            <img src="<?= 'http://www.google.com' . $current[0]->icon['data']?>" alt="weather"?>
            <span class="condition">
            <?= $current[0]->temp_f['data'] ?>&deg; F,
            <?= $current[0]->condition['data'] ?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <h2>Forecast</h2>
        <? foreach ($forecast_list as $forecast) : ?>
        <div class="weather">
            <img src="<?= 'http://www.google.com' . $forecast->icon['data']?>" alt="weather"?>
            <div><?= $forecast->day_of_week['data']; ?></div>
            <span class="condition">
                <?= $forecast->low['data'] ?>&deg; F - <?= $forecast->high['data'] ?>&deg; F,
                <?= $forecast->condition['data'] ?>
            </span>
        </div>  
        <? endforeach ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Good luck!

Comment: and where i can get the listing of the city (to get the right wordding and change it to french

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo has a feed - it's RSS, and not JSON - but it's always up to date and very simple to use. You can find more details here:

http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Answer (score 0):

this is also a good response/answer : [Parse weather data from Weatherbug in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378837/parse-weather-data-from-weatherbug-in-php)